# How to keep Celery running in Django (drf) + Redis + WSGI (EC2)

Tags: django, redis, django-rest-framework, celery

I don't think its a very new question. I just could not find the right answer. I am trying to use Celery for background tasks while implementing a backend with the Django Rest Framework. I have a Redis server.

Celery is working as expected with

```
celery worker -A my_project --loglevel=info
```

However, it does not work if I sop this command. How do I keep that running? I have found a blog with `supervisor`. I just want to know what is the standard (as well as easier) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is go for docker and use `docker-compose` for your services. But if you're just testing stuff:

```sh
$ nohup celery worker -A my_project --loglevel=info &
```

`&` is used to take the process to the background, you can recall it using `fg`, suspend it to bg using `Ctrl + Z`, `nohup` makes sure that celery will remain functioning even if you close the `ssh` session.

Edit: The only drawback using this method, is that if the process exits, then you'll have to invoke it again. In a production environment, you should go for docker with docker-compose.

Comment: all the documents I have seen, this approach is good for development not for production.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you care to elaborate?

Comment: I was actually looking for https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @sadat I found this post helpful - https://t.ly/Cwdt